# Scala vs Java method invocation

Tags: java, scala, methods

I had to write my own JDK dynamic proxy to provide the ability of dynamic interface implementation. Since I work with `akka` it has to be written in Scala. But I faced with some pretty strange behavior differs from Java:

```
object Main extends App {
    println(classOf[Message].getDeclaredMethod("msg")
                            .invoke(Message("Test"), null)) 
                          //throws IllegalArgumentException
}

case class Message(message: String){
  def msg() = message
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:2)
    at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:1)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:1)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/ZyEfa7)

But I in Java it works fine:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(Message.class.getDeclaredMethod("msg")
              .invoke(new Message(), null)); //prints Message
}

public static class Message{
    public String msg(){
        return "Message";
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/41yMyM)

Why does Scala throw exception? And how to fix it?

Comment: I bet Scala wraps the `null` argument differently, into its own arguments instead of to mean _no arguments_. Just remove it from the invocation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is right, without the null yields what you expect

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Very interesting, but don't you know the exact Scala magic about null?

Comment: Akka has Java interface, you are not obliged to write in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I can demonstrate what is going on:

```
class TheClass { 
  def theMethod:Unit = { println("It's me the method"); } 
}

scala> classOf[TheClass].getDeclaredMethod("theMethod").invoke(new TheClass, null)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

scala> classOf[TheClass].getDeclaredMethod("theMethod").invoke(new TheClass)
It's me the method
res1: Object = null
```

As expected, but now have a look at this:

```
scala> classOf[TheClass]
      .getDeclaredMethod("theMethod").invoke(new TheClass, Array.empty)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

Versus this:

```
scala> classOf[TheClass]
       .getDeclaredMethod("theMethod").invoke(new TheClass, Array.empty : _*)
It's me the method
res4: Object = null
```

Notice the difference between the invokes: `.invoke(new TheClass, Array.empty)` vs `.invoke(new TheClass, Array.empty : _*)`. What happens is that `invoke`s second argument is a *varargs*, which should be turned into a array under the hood, when it's given a plain `Array.empty` or `null` scalac is replacing them with `Array(Array.empty)` and `Array(null)`. When the argument is not provided it's actually `Array.empty` and when we use `: _*` it just telling the compiler that the argument we are proving **is** the varargs itself.